# Does the convergence of integrals against $H^1_0$ functions imply boundedness in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

In order to show something, I would like to have this strange side result, which seems obvious yet surprisingly I cannot find a way to show it "rigoriously".

Suppose we have a sequence $(u_n) \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$, such that 
$$
n \int u_n^-v \to C(v)
$$
as $n \to \infty$. Here $(\cdot)^-$ denotes the non-positive part of the original function, $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ is a test function and  $C(v)$ is just something depending on $v$ (not relevant here, the point is that this is bounded, which means that the integral with the sequence is of order $O(n^{-1}))$. From that we can infer that in the limit $u$ (and it was shown we can pass to the limit etc.) will be non-negative, as this is the only way to avoid the blow-up. Can we thus conclude that 
$$
||n\,u_n^-||_{L^2} \leq C_2 ?
$$

It seems perfectly obvious, yet any standard inequality does not allow me to conclude it. In particular, playing with
$$
\int n^2\, u_n^- \,u_n^-
$$
does not seem to yield anything fruitful. I suppose the difficulty lies in the fact that this order of $O(n^{-1})$ is 'hidden' in the integral and it cannot be extracted that easily. Or, and this far more likely, I am be missing something obvious. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The more and more I think about it, the more likely it seems that the answer is actually no...

Comment: Okay, I think the answer is positive that's thanks to the fact that the original bound holds for all the test functions, which means that there $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$ we should have $|\int_{\Omega}u_n^-v| \leq 1/n$. That means we have $|u_n^-|\leq 1/n$ uniformly, as for any potential regions above this bound we can choose a test function sufficiently large on this region to rule them out. So without this uniformity we would never be able to find a fixed $n_0$. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have $nu_n^-$ bounded in $L^2$. You would have this if you knew that the sequence $nu_n^-$ is weakly convergent in $L^2$. But the latter requires testing against arbitrary $v\in L^2$. Your test functions are in $H_0^1$, which (by Sobolev embedding) are in some $L^q$ with $q>2$.

A counterexample can be obtained as follows. Let $q$ be as above and choose $p$ so that $1/p+1/q=1$. Pick a nonnegative compactly supported function $f\in L^p\setminus L^2$; this is possible because $p<2$. Specifically, it should smooth except for a singularity like $|x-x_0|^{-\alpha}$.

Let $u_n^- = \min(f,n)/n$; this function is in $H^1$. Since $nu_n^- \to f$ in $L^p$, we have $\int nu_n^-v$ converging for every $v\in L^q$. On the other hand, $\|nu_n^-\|_{L^2}\to \|f\|_{L^2}= \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort! I have some doubts though: 1) In your counterexample, is $(u_n^-) \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$? It does not seem to be the case since $f$ is not even in $L^2(\Omega)$. 2) What would you say about my second comment above? Usually, as in say Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations, we get some sort of uniformity if something is true testing against all test functions. That's why I'm inclined to think we get a on order of $O(n^{-1})$ uniformly, not just in the integral.

Comment: Basically, if you know that you have weak convergence against $H^1_0$ test functions, then you know that you have boundedness in the dual of $H^1_0$. You might hope that this would imply boundedness in the dual of $L^{2^*}$ where $p^*$ is the Sobolev conjugate, because of some density idea. But $\frac{1}{2^*}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{d}=\frac{d-1}{2d}$, so $2^*=\frac{2d}{d-1}$. Now the Holder conjugate is $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^*}}=\frac{1}{\frac{2d-(d-1)}{2d}}=\frac{2d}{d+1}<2$.

Comment: Yea, I get this part that and accept we cannot say anything about $L^2$ directly, but if we forget about $L^2$ and just think about it this way: clearly $\int_{\Omega} (u_n^-) v = O(n^{-1}) \, \forall v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Does that not imply that $u_n^- = O(n^{-1})$? So for $n$ large enough we can uniformly bound $u_n^- \leq 1/n$. In the light of what you are saying this argument is false, but I just do not see why.

Comment: Okay I think now I know. The choice of $n_0$ can be different for each $v$, so we do not get the uniformity. Is that right?

Comment: @PinkandFloyd Yes; $|\langle u^-_n v \rangle| \leq C_v n^{-1}$ but $C_v$ can be arbitrarily large in principle (and actually does become arbitrarily large in this particular case).